# Hiding the TabBar on iOS 11 using Xamarin is leaving a white rectangle

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

Prior to iOS 11, I was using this code inside a custom renderer for the TabPage to conditionally hide the TabBar in my app:

```
private void ToggleTabs(object sender, bool hideTabs)
{
    TabBar.Hidden = hideTabs;

    TabBar.Frame = TabBar.Hidden
        ? new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y, TabBar.Frame.Width, 0)
        : new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y, TabBar.Frame.Width, tabBarHeight);
}
```

where `tabBarHeight` is calculated when the TabBar is constructed (it should always be 49 according to the docs, but I hate magic numbers).

The problem that I'm now running into is that even though I'm collapsing the frame, there is still a white rectangle left where the tab bar used to be. I have only noticed this behavior on devices running iOS 11 deployed from XCode 9.

I found some information about SafeAreaInsets that I thought may have been causing the problem, but 0 is always returned unless I'm running on an iPhone X, so that seems to have been a bust.

It looks like the iOS 11 SDK may be to blame, but I can't figure out the work around.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Setting `myTabBarController.TabBar.Hidden = true` works as expected on both the Sim and my 6S. Since it's a "custom renderer" perhaps you need to call `SetNeedsDisplay` after hiding the TabBar?

Comment: I can't reproduce on my side ,too . Could you provide us a simple project?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
            TabBar.Hidden = tabBarHidden;

            // The solution to the space left behind the invisible tab bar
            if (tabBarHidden)
            {
                View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y,
                                                                 View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 0);
                View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                                 View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Height + 49);
            }
            else
            {
                View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y,
                                                                 View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 49);
                View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                                 View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Height - 49);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to add a little tweak for when the phone gets rotated, the views broke again, so this code also gets called when the rotation happens. The little wiggle of the view height seems to sort it all out... Very Hacky but 3-4 hrs later, I accepted the hack and moved on!

```
       if (RootTabPage._fullScreen)
        {
            View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y,
                                                             View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 0);
            if( View.Frame.Height == View.Subviews[0].Frame.Height )
                View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                                 View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height + 2 );
            else
                View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                                 View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height + 3 );
        }
        else
        {
            View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y,
                                                             View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, th);
            View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                             View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height );
        }
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation about what the code does and why it solves the question from your point of view?

Comment: Sure, there seems to be some underlying issue between Xamarin layout and iOS. so tweaking the view height slightly causes the layout to be performed and the white box disappear. I tried numerous links and solutions, but for iOS 11 with screen rotation this was the only thing that solved the rotation with a hidden tab bar (plus without rotation)